# Hibernate 5: Mapping by annotation doesn't work and throws MappingException (unknown entity)

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have already checked solutions for the problem, but it did not help.

I am practicing Spring+Hibernate. Previously I have mapped entities by .xml file. But now I tried to do it by annotations cause it looks more comfortable. But unfortunately, I got

```
Unknown entity: milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole
```

So I have the next **model** file:

```
package milkiv.easyword.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity (name = "UserRole")
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id", updatable = false, unique = true)
    private int roleId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email field can not be empty or missed.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 59, message = "Email field must have from 5 to 128 symbols.")
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public int getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    //INFO: SPRING REQUIRE NAME ROLES IN FORMAT - ROLE_rolename
    this.name = "ROLE_".concat(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return (name.hashCode()*31+roleId)*31;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final UserRole other = (UserRole) obj;
    if (this.roleId != other.roleId) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(this.name, other.name);
    }
}
```

my **spring-context.xml** file:

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    //added when tried to resolve the problem.
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole"/>
    <property name="configLocations">
        <value>classpath:resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>   

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="milkiv.easyword"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

And hibernate configuration file **hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/myurl</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">easywordweb</property>-->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <mapping resource="resources/milkiv/easyword/models/User.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="resources/milkiv/easyword/models/UserSessions.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="resources/milkiv/easyword/models/Language.hbm.xml"/>
    <!--<mapping class="milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole"/>-->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But when I try to call any function from the UserRoleManager (`UserRoleManager implements UserRoleDAO<UserRole>`) in UnitTest I have the next **exceptions**:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:219)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:344)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:309)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:616)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager.create(UserRoleManager.java:37)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a48099a0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2bdb1f79.create(<generated>)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a48099a0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c468ebb.create(<generated>)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManagerTest.createTest(UserRoleManagerTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:616)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:341)
    ... 54 more
milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManagerTest  Time elapsed: 0.531 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateQueryException: UserRole is not mapped [from UserRole where name = :name]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserRole is not mapped [from UserRole where name = :name]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:176)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:344)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:309)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(HibernateTemplate.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(HibernateTemplate.java:882)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager.readByName(UserRoleManager.java:30)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a48099a0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2bdb1f79.readByName(<generated>)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a48099a0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c468ebb.readByName(<generated>)
    at milkiv.easyword.managers.UserRoleManagerTest.EraseTestData(UserRoleManagerTest.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserRole is not mapped [from UserRole where name = :name]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1825)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:895)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:341)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserRole is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3678)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    ... 49 more
```

The message is clear, but the cause of it - no. 
Please if anyone have any ideas can you help me? I will appreciate any help.
Thank's in advance.

**EDIT:** I use Hibernate 5.0.1.Final version.

**EDIT:** Tried this one. Also doesn't work for me:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
        <value>milkiv.easyword.models</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocations">
        <value>classpath:resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This is incorrect `<property name="packagesToScan" value="milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole"/>`

Comment: @v.ladynev, Oooh. I see. It has to be without UserRole. I have tried also `value="milkiv.easyword.models"` and it doesn't work as well. I've read in setter description for the packegesToScan variable that it is that I need. "Specify packages to search for autodetection of your entity classes in the classpath".  I've also tried to set annotatedClasses variable. I update my post.

Comment: Try to begin from a simply console application without Spring. Then add Spring stuff without web. You have a lot of unnecessary things:  for an example, specify a table name with `@Entity` and `@Table`. `unique = true` for a primary key, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not know about your annotated class, you need to tell hibernate where it is, with this property in the session factory xml:

```
<mapping package="milkiv.easyword.models"/>
```

or directly a class:

```
<mapping class="milkiv.easyword.models.UserRole"/>
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/ch01.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I have tried the second one solution and unfortunately for me it doesn't work. As well as the first one. The same exceptions occurred.

Comment: how are you instantiating the session factory? have you using AnnotationConfiguration? because if you are using the legacy HibernateUtils it byt default does not support annotated entities.

Comment: I've used HibernateTemplate from the org.springframework.orm.hibernate5 cause it doing all work with sessions instead of me or it is the bad decision? And inject into HibernateTemplate as sessionFactory LocalSessionFactoryBean from the same package. So look like the problem is with the LocalSessionFactoryBean. I tried to inject annotatedClasses and annotatedPackages values into LocalSessionFactoryBean but it didn't work as well.

Comment: I recommend you to use annottions instead of xml for beans definitions, and moreover if you are using LocalSessionFactoryBean, configure all hibernate relative properties using this class instead of hibernate xml config file. You look at this minimum example: http://www.marcobehler.com/make-it-so-java-db-connections-and-transactions-html/hibernate-jpa-setting-up-hibernate-with-spring.html

Comment: `<mapping package="milkiv.easyword.models"/>` this is incorrect.